# regex to validate string of 10 characters which are all digits

Tags: regex

I want to match a string of 10 characters and all of them need to be integers. How do I write a regular expression to check for this format.

Valid values should be something like - '1234567890', '4321567890'

Comment: Please read some of the _fantastic_ manuals on regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (not all dialects support this):

```
[0-9]{10}
```

Another option:

```
[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

If you match the whole string, don't forget the `^` and `$` markers:

```
^[0-9]{10}$
```

Comment: Yes.  After the edit (i.e. after including the version with anchors), it is.

Comment: @devnull: It is also possible that a RE will be supposed to match the whole string without the anchors. For example, `-x` in grep, `re.match` in Python and other similar modifiers in other languages/tools.